# Nginx won't start, says "could not build test test_types_hash"

Tags: nginx

Here's my nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 1;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 2048;
    # debug_connection 192.168.1.1;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    server_tokens off;
    include mime.types;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nodelay on;

    gzip on;

    # http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpGzipModule#gzip_disable
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_types text/javascript text/css text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss application/x-javascript;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.ngx;

    #tcp_nopush on;
    #keepalive_timeout  0;
}
```

When I try to start nginx, here's what I see:

```
nginx: [warn] duplicate MIME type "text/javascript" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:27
nginx: [emerg] could not build the test_types_hash, you should increase either test_types_hash_max_size: 2048 or test_types_hash_bucket_size: 64
```

This identical configuration has worked previously with no issues. What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After banging my head against the wall for a couple of minutes, I just decided "what the heck, I'll fix the first error and see what happens." Lo and behold, removing the extraneous text/javascript MIME type in the gzip_types declaration fixed the problem.

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of anyone arriving here late to the party but not exeriencing that first message:

Your fix of the first error had the side-effect of shortening the line which had caused the second message.

In my own case, the silly mistake was to place the list of MIME types in quotes.  Leave them unquoted.

You can't increase the bucket size for the 'test_types_hash' since there isn't a directive (ref. https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/203) so reducing the list of MIME types is the only option.

Ref. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#types_hash_bucket_size

Answer (score 0):

Even if the OP is more than nine year old, the error still occurs.
I usually do a Web search on such issues first and found [this tip](https://handcodedstudio.co.uk/tips/solving-nginx-could-not-build-server-names-hash-error/):

*You can resolve the error, by adding this line to nginx.conf in the http block:*

```
server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
```

But that didn't solve it. Only when I removed the last "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.*" MIME type, the error disappeared.

I noted that someone has raised this as an [issue with nginx.org](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?11,279012) more than five years ago but the issue is still open.

To make a long story short, better avoid the MS Office XML mime types in the gzip_types directive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `server_names_hash_bucket_size` directive into SERVER block, not into HTTP. Also it must be placed after gzip_types.

Here is the example from my working config:

```
gzip on;
gzip_comp_level 9;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_vary on;

gzip_types
    application/atom+xml
    application/geo+json
    application/javascript
    application/x-javascript
    application/json
    application/ld+json
    application/manifest+json
    application/rdf+xml
    application/rss+xml
    application/xhtml+xml
    application/xml
    font/eot
    font/otf
    font/ttf
    image/svg+xml
    text/css
    text/javascript
    text/plain
    text/xml

server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
```